# How to make skrollr.js works for scroll spy websites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, skrollr, jquery-scrollify

I Created a website with using [`scrollify`](https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify). Can I integrate [`Skrollr.js`](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) with this project for achieving parallax kind of animation on scroll event. 
    Basically Skrollr js works based on pixel by pixel. While using scrollify js the section are positioned not by pixel.

NOTE:
 - on page transition I need animation(`page contents sliding from left to right`) on the fly.

Please check the below link.
http://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/index.html

while scrolling using the above link when the second section appears contents from the second section should slide from left to right.

Thanks,
Gowri Shankar